# postgresql trigger for filling new column on insert

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have a table `Table_A`:

```
\d "Table_A";
                           Table "public.Table_A"
  Column  |  Type   |                          Modifiers
----------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------
 id       | integer | not null default nextval('"Table_A_id_seq"'::regclass)
 field1   | bigint  |
 field2   | bigint  |
```

and now I want to add a new column. So I run:

```
ALTER TABLE "Table_A" ADD COLUMN "newId" BIGINT DEFAULT NULL;
```

now I have:

```
\d "Table_A";
                           Table "public.Table_A"
  Column  |  Type   |                          Modifiers
----------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------
 id       | integer | not null default nextval('"Table_A_id_seq"'::regclass)
 field1   | bigint  |
 field2   | bigint  |
 newId    | bigint  |
```

And I want `newId` to be filled with the same value as `id` for new/updated rows.

I created the following function and trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION autoFillNewId() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  NEW."newId" := NEW."id";
  RETURN NEW;
END $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER "newIdAutoFill" AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON "Table_A" EXECUTE PROCEDURE autoFillNewId();
```

Now if I insert something with:

```
INSERT INTO "Table_A" values (97, 1, 97);
```

`newId` is not filled:

```
select * from "Table_A" where id = 97;
 id | field1   | field2   | newId
----+----------+----------+-------
 97 |        1 |       97 |
```

> Note: I also tried with `FOR EACH ROW` from some answer here in SO

What's missing me?

Comment: You need a `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE` trigger.

Comment: thanks, it works. I thought it would be just a simple detail,but I was finding hard to solve it :) Why does it need to be a BEFORE ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a `BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ... FOR EACH ROW` trigger to make this work:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "newIdAutoFill"
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON "Table_A"
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE autoFillNewId();
```

A `BEFORE` trigger takes place before the new row is inserted or updated, so you can still makes changes to the field values. An `AFTER` trigger is useful to implement some side effect, like auditing of changes or cascading changes to other tables.

By default, triggers are `FOR EACH STATEMENT` and then the `NEW` parameter is not defined (because the trigger does not operate on a row). So you have to specify `FOR EACH ROW`.

Comment: You should add BEFORE before INSERT OR UPDATE in answer snippet